Sum of an item sold over a given period
I'm trying to figure out how to get the sum of an item sold within the last # of days.
I've tried many variations of the formula below but I can't seem to get it right and I've scoured the internet for a solution but couldn't find on for my specific scenario oddly enough.
SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,C:C, >=TODAY()-30)

What I'm looking for specifically is the total quantity of an item sold over the last 90 days as an example.


I figured it out (Thanks to Leila Gharani)
I had the wrong range.  It should have been the Qty column.
Once I change that around The values I needed for a given date range was able to sum for that period.
Here's the correct formula.
SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,">="&TODAY()-90)

